# ggplot coordinate grid frame forces points to be indiscernable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a very simple bivariate scatter plot using ggplot and am not able to do so effectively because ggplot creates a large x-y coordinate grid frame. I am able to obtain the desired plot with qplot, however when I try to use the equivalent ggplot code, I encounter the issue.

Version info

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- R: 3.4.4
- ggplot2: 3.0.0

Here is example code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes("mpg", "cyl")) +
  geom_point()
```

And the output I am getting is:
[ggplot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHFyF.png)

But when I run the qplot equivalent:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
```

I get the desired output:
[qplot output (what I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdGAT.png)

I have tried re-starting R, clearing my environment and manually setting x and y limits, but nothing is working. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be quoting `mpg` and `cyl` with `"` in your ggplot call, that's the difference between your two attempts. `ggplot` is set up to deal with unquoted column names.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much @Marius!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid double quotes in aesthetics ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))+geom_point().